# Binding one control to another's DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I bind my wpf window to app layer class (WindowVM.cs) using `DataContext` in Window.xaml.cs constructor (`DataContext = WindowVM`). But, one control (`btnAdd`) I want to bind to Window.xaml.cs property. So in Window.xaml.cs constructor I add `this.btnAdd.DataContext`.   This is Window.xaml.cs constructor and property to which I want bind `Button` `btnAdd`:

```
    public Window()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = WindowVM;
        this.btnAdd.DataContext = this;
    }

    public RelayCommand Add
    {
        get
        {
            return _add == null ? _add= new RelayCommand(AddPP, CanAddPP) : _add;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged("Add");
        }
    }
```

Xaml looks like this (class PP is WindowVM property):

```
<TextBox Name="txtName" Text="{Binding PP.Name, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Name="txtSurname" Text="{Binding PP.Surname, ValidatesOnDataErrors=true, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Button Command="{Binding Add}" Content="Add" ... />
```

And - everything works, but console output this:

```
BindingExpression path error: 'Add' property not found on 'object' ''WindowVM'...
```

In next calls there isn't any console output error for property Add.

Now I am a little bit confused because of this error. Is this error because of first `DataContext` (to WindowVM), because there isn't property Add, but with line `this.btnAdd.DataContext` property Add is found and it's the reason that it works?

Comment: So why are you using MVVM(or a similar) if you aren't going to put the command in the ViewModel?  The ViewModel should be where the Command is.  There should really be ZERO code in the Window's code behind.

Comment: I put command in ViewModel, but have problems because I need to close window. This binding works: {Binding ElementName=MyUsersView, Path=Add}. But, I will try with this: http://blog.excastle.com/2010/07/25/mvvm-and-dialogresult-with-no-code-behind/ and put Command in ViewModel then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the DataContext-Property, your Window resets the Bindings of it's child controls. Even the Binding of your button. 
At this Point (before "button.DataContext = this" is evaluated) "Add" is searched in WindowVM. After this you set the Window class as buttons DC, and everything works fine.

To avoid the initial error, swap two lines from this

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = WindowVM;
    this.btnAdd.DataContext = this;
}
```

to this

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.btnAdd.DataContext = this;
    DataContext = WindowVM;
}
```

Comment: how can I set keybinding to this button now? <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Key="F8" /> not working

Comment: Your KeyBinding looks fine, but you still need to catch it with a CommandBinding
<Window.CommandBindings>
<CommandBinding Command={Binding SaveCommand} Executed="CommandExecuted_Handler" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
Where "CommandExecuted_Handler" is the Event-Handler for it.
You can find the Documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.executed.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the `DataContext` of the `Button` in the XAML using a `RelativeSource`:

```
<Button Command="{Binding Add}" Content="Add" DataContext="{Binding Add, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and I know this is an oldish post but I think this might help someone who stumbles on this in the future.

what I did was declare the viewmodels as resources

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:LocationListViewModel x:Key="LocationList" />
    <local:LocationNewViewModel x:Key="NewLocation" />
    <code:BinaryImageConverter x:Key="imgConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

then which ever control I wanted to be associated with said viewmodel I added this to their datacontext

```
<TabItem x:Name="tabSettingsLocations" x:Uid="tabSettingsLocations" 
                 Header="Locations"
                 DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=LocationList}">....

<TabItem x:Name="tbSettingsLocationsAdd" x:Uid="tbSettingsLocationsAdd" 
         Header="Add New"
         DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewLocation}">....

<Image x:Name="imgSettingsLocationMapNew" x:Uid="imgSettingsLocationMapNew" 
         Source="{Binding Map, Converter={StaticResource imgConverter}, 
         Mode=TwoWay}"
         DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewLocation}" />
```

So in my example above I have Listview bound to the list viewmodel and I create a new single location for my new entry. You will notice that by creating it as a resource I can bind the tabitem and the image (which is not a child of the tab item) to the new location viewmodel.

My command for the addnew location is in the new location viewmodel.

```
<TabItem x:Name="tbSettingsLocationsAdd" x:Uid="tbSettingsLocationsAdd" 
         Header="Add New"
         DataContext="{StaticResource ResourceKey=NewLocation}">....

    <Button x:Name="btnSettingsLocationSaveAdd" x:Uid="btnSettingsLocationSaveAdd" Content="Submit" Margin="0,80,10,0" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="75"
        Command="{Binding AddCommand}" />.....
```

Which is the child of the tabitem I bound to the new location viewmodel.

I hope that helps.